# Wordpress s2 member plugin not working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, user-registration

I had use the s2 member plugin for registration.When i register it as new member it shows password where send by email but i cant get any mail upon registration please anyone help me

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using the plugin on local server. If you wants to receive e-mails after registration then first you have to upload your website on internet. Because any plugin that use to send email, doesn't work in local server.

Comment: ok i will check